# If Cell in Range Matches ComboBox Value Then right Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a time line via Excel and VBA, having the hours (1-24) listed in the range A1:A24; I created a ComboBox, filled the list with that very range and now I'm trying to link these two, so that if I choose a certain hour in the ComboBox, Excel will display "Test" one cell to the right of that specific cell from the given range (e.g. if I select "8" in the ComboBox, then Excel will display "Test" in B8, since the value of A8 is "8")

This is how far I got with the little knowledge about VBA that I have:

```
Private Sub Combobox1_Change()

    For Each cell In Range("A1:A24")
        If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Test"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

It would be great if someone could help me work this out!

Answer (score 0):

If the list is ordered 1 - 24, simply use

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = [A1]                    ' or wherever your list starts
    MyRange(ComboBox1.Value, 2) = "Test"  ' address the range object by row, column
End Sub
```

Be carefull with `If cell.Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then` ... `ComboBox1` returns a `String`, your Cell may contain numbers and the `If` may not work (at least here this is the case).

A more generalized routine scanning the whole list and not relying on its ascending sort order (you may soon have a list with "Apple", "Banana", "Cherimoya", ...)

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim MyRange As Range, Idx As Integer

    Set MyRange = [A1]                       ' or whereever your list starts
    Idx = 1

    Do While MyRange(Idx, 1) <> ""           ' start processing
        If Str(MyRange(Idx, 1)) = Str(ComboBox1) Then
            If MyRange(Idx, 2) = "" Then     ' bonus: do a toggle
                MyRange(Idx, 2) = "Test"
            Else
                MyRange(Idx, 2) = ""
            End If
            Exit Do                          ' or not for full list processing
        End If
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```